# Is there a standardized file format for parametrised solid modelling?

Tags: computer-aided-design

Is there a standardized file format for parametrised solid modelling? I am familiar with STEP and IGES file formats for saving solid models, but AFAIK they don’t store information regarding parameters, so that the another person (not the one who created the file) can modify some parameter.

I know that every proprietary file formate (Solidworks, Inventor and so on) stores the parameters, but I am interested in a non proprietary file.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not Standardized, no.

Comment: There are open parametric formats, but they are linked to their own (open) software as .SLDPRT is to SolidWorks

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Is there an open parametric format that is widely accepted/used?

Comment: .FCStd "FreeCAD Standard" is open source, and can easily be converted into other neutral formats as the Open CASCADE geometry kernel on which FreeCAD is based natively supports STEP, IGES, glTF, OBJ, STL and VRML. I wouldn't say it's "widely accepted/used", however.

Comment: You might also be interested in OpenSCAD, which is code-based so the parameters are integral to the file